# Count how many events occurs after user logs in

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, performance

I need to count events (enrollments) occurred after the user log into the application.

All events are registered in a SQL server database in a table events like this.

**Table description**

```
ClientID | ApplicationID | logtime | eventid | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

> ClientID: Client (workstation) that generates the event
>
> ApplicationID: Application that generated the event (Different apps
>   can use the DB)
>
> Logtime: Time that the events was generated eventid: type of events.
>   There are many buy i'm interested in two of them: "login",
>   "enrollment". There is no "logout"
>
> event data1-4: different info regarding the eventid
>      - For eventid=login: data3 saves the username connected
>      - For eventid=enrollment: data1 saves a reference to the person enrolled.

Well, What I want to get is something like this

```
Username | Date      | Enrollments
-----------------------------
User1     2014-06-01   11
User2     2014-06-01   6
```

... and so on

I already wrote a query but it's terribly inefficient (and not accurate) and I'd like to improve it.

```
DECLARE @sdate as datetime
SET @sdate = '2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT date, username, sum(enrollments) enrollments
FROM (
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),e.logtime,120) as date, upper(e.data3 ) username, 
(SELECT count(*)
FROM  events r2
WHERE r2.clientID = e.clientID
AND r2.stateid = 'login' 
AND r2.ApplicationID = 'application1'
AND r2.logtime between e.logtime AND (SELECT top 1 r3.logtime FROM events r3
                                        WHERE r3.logtime > e.logtime
                                        AND r3.stateid = 'enrollment' 
                                        AND r3.clientID = e.clientID
                                        AND r3.ApplicationID in 'application1'
                                        ORDER BY logtime asc) 
) as enrollments
FROM events e
WHERE e.logtime > @sdate 
AND e.stateid = 'enrollment' 
AND e.ApplicationID = 'application1'
) data
GROUP BY date, username
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
ClientID | ApplicationID | logtime | eventid | data1 | data3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c132    application1    2013-01-05 00:20:48.400 login   NULL    user1
c132    application1    2013-01-05 00:21:50.393 enrollment  30012   NULL
c132    application1    2013-01-05 00:22:57.330 enrollment  30015   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:29:49.197 login   NULL    user2
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:34:52.993 enrollment  30021   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:36:17.723 enrollment  30022   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:37:59.623 enrollment  30026   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:39:10.770 enrollment  30028   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:41:47.170 enrollment  30031   NULL
c132    application1    2013-01-05 00:54:20.890 enrollment  30040   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:55:01.530 enrollment  30041   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:56:51.877 enrollment  30044   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 00:57:52.420 enrollment  30045   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 01:00:04.630 enrollment  30050   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 01:01:19.583 enrollment  30056   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 01:08:56.073 login   NULL    user2
c129    application1    2013-01-05 01:09:31.793 enrollment  30073   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 01:12:38.490 enrollment  30081   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 07:29:25.350 login   NULL    user2
c129    application1    2013-01-05 07:30:38.087 enrollment  30207   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 07:42:18.793 enrollment  30214   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 07:44:36.540 enrollment  30218   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 07:46:10.693 enrollment  30220   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 08:41:46.073 enrollment  30266   NULL
c129    application1    2013-01-05 08:42:44.627 enrollment  30268   NULL
```

Comment: The rules for database normilization has be mercilessly slaughtered in your schema.

Comment: I gave this a stab, but--as a given client/application could have any number of sequential users/logins--associating a given "enrollment" event with its "originating login" event is prohibitively difficult, particularly without sample data to work with.

Comment: I know how bad the database is designed but I can't do anything about it. I need to deal with that. I added an example of how does the DB looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's going to perform any better but you can try:

```
select
  username
, enrollment_date
, count(1)
from (
    select
      el_start.data3 as username
    , date_format(e_enrl.logtime,'%Y-%m-%d') enrollment_date -- this is MySQL date format function, you'll need to substitute SQL Server date format function
    from
      events el_start
      join events el_end on el_start.logtime<el_end.logtime and el_start.application_id='application1' and el_end.application_id='application1' and el_start.event_id='login' and el_end.event_id='login'
      join events e_enrl on el_start.logtime<e_enrl.logtime and el_end.logtime>e_enrl.logtime and e_enrl.application_id='application1' and e_enrl.event_id='enrollment'
      left outer join events el_middle el_middle on el_start.logtime<el_middle.logtime and el_end.logtime>el_middle.logtime and el_middle.application_id='application1' and el_middle.event_id='login'
    where 1=1
      and el_middle.event_id is null
  ) enrollments
group by username, enrollment_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. Maybe you can explain me the logic you used so I can try to make it.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work: it's difficult to check these without having all of the tables set up locally. The idea is that el_start should be the logtime of one login, el_end should be the logtime of the subsequent login and el_middle should be the logtime of logins in between and should be null, i.e. there should be no logins between the two we've chosen to guarantee we're getting two subsequent logins. e_enrl should be all the entrollments that occur between el_start and el_end. You may want to take a quick look at the inner subquery which should have all enrollments plus login before and after

Comment: What I was trying to do if either: 
-counting all the enrollments after a 'login' events on the same station until another 'login event or no 'login' events.
- or for each 'enrollment' look the the first 'login' before the enrollment on the same station. 
The query I posted is intended to do the first case but it doesn't work. I will post the other query tomorrow (it works but it's too inefficient)  to see if it helps.